# Display of spreadsheet values in Stack Overflow

Tags: support, markdown

I would like to insert spreadsheet values into the body of Stack Overflow questions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996811/sort-values-in-an-excel-spreadsheet).

Comment: Select the text and press `ctrl + k`

Comment: Both links points to the same post.

Answer (score 3):

Select the text and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>
Make sure the text is separated by space(1/2/3)
Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> or `{}` option in the stackoverflow editor

In general, whenever you wonder how a specific post was formatted, just click the edit-link and you will see (only works partially on meta).