# Formatting for Q/A about spreadsheet cells and cell functions

Tags: support, code-formatting, formatting

When answering questions about spreadsheets, I don't know how to format sample spreadsheet sections. These can be ranges of spreadsheet cells, typically under 10x20 cells, some of which may include formulas. Formulas alone can be formatted as code, but sometimes spreadsheet Q/A involve more than one formula in specific locations on the sample spreadsheet section. Is there some hidden awesome or at least beautiful way to format sample spreadsheet sections?

Example of a sample spreadsheet 6x2 with two formulas:

```
          A         B
1         5         3
2         3         =Function1
3         2         =Function2
4         4         
5         1
6         2
```

Where `Function1` is

```
=ROWS(A1:A6)
```

And `Function2` is

```
=COUNTIF(OFFSET(A1,B2-B1,0,B1,1),">1"))
```

(The function counts the number of values greater than 1 in the last 3 cells of the range `A1:A6`.)

Comment: What about an ascii table? like this: http://pastebin.com/cQ7RUV7Z

Comment: @Magish, I can type vertical pipes, too. I am asking about the best or preferred way of handling spreadsheet Q/As on SO. If this is it, make it into a full-fledged answer.

Comment: I don't think there's an official way to do it, I was just suggesting a way to do it. I don't think stack has a utility for it.

Comment: Related: [How do I paste data on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275458/1595451)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some hidden awesome or at least beautiful way to format sample spreadsheet sections?

Unfortunately there isn't.

If the sample value lengths are short, as you did, use spaces to separate the data  as this is the simplest way and some spreadsheet apps are able to separate this structure in columns, but if they are large, and the values are wrapped on your spreadsheet app insert a picture and add a link to file containing the sample data.

Related

- [How do I paste spreadsheet data on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275458/1595451)
- [Display of spreadsheet values in Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312202/1595451)
- [How do I format my data as a table with doubled line separators in my posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313648/1595451)
- [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375532/1595451) (currently deleted) to [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/1595451)
- [Is there Markdown to create tables?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73566/289691)